# Understanding atomic operations and race conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, atomic

Lets say I have a collection with a `views_count`, `males_views_count` and `females_views_count` fields. I would like to be able to `$inc` (increment) the count fields respectively when a page is viewed.

The issue with this is I receive several concurrent connections, and a race condition may occur.

I've been reading about atomic operations in Mongodb. Where they typically have a succeed or fail approach. Either the record is written or it isn't. Does that mean I need to create the logic to determine whether the operation failed and if so, retry it?

Going back to my scenario. What if I wanted to make every view count (even when a race conditions occur). I know Mongodb locks are slightly different than traditional RDBMS'. Typically, I would implement an optimistic locking technique. Similar to:

```
begin
  # .. do work .. determine if user is a male or a female
  stat.save
rescue StaleDocumentError
  stat.reload
  retry
end
```

Or are atomic operations meant to prevent race conditions as it is the server who does the update and it is authoritative about what the truth is? If so, do we still need to implement optimistic/pessimistic locking techniques, or will Mongodb take care of that for us if we use atomic operations?

Comment: $inc is atomic, no race condition will occur, with atomic operations (as well as with many other things) only one operation at time can run on the document and the server nevrer picks a partial document state, only one after or before an operation

Comment: If one atomic operation hits the "stale record", what happens to it? Does the operation retry/re-queue itself? Or is the operation lost (the record not saved)?

Comment: It can never hit a stale record, it is impossible, the server will never pick a partial document and since atomic opertions, as stennie says, run in queue you will never get a stale document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using atomic operations such as [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/) there is no race condition.  If you have two increments from different threads they will be applied in the order received by the server and the end outcome on the document will be the same after both operations are applied.

If you are updating fields to specific values using [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/%5d), the "winning" value will be the last `$set` applied.  If your application use case may lead to conflicting updates of the same field, then optimistic locking/versioning would be useful.

As far as exception handling goes, you should assume that any database operation could potentially result in a server exception (network error, duplicate key, ...) and retry as appropriate.  There isn't any special logic required for atomic updates versus non-atomic updates, unless you choose to implement your own optimistic locking (in which case you would probably refetch the current version of the document and retry the operation).

The MongoDB manual covers a few different patterns in [Isolate Sequence of Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/).